# Determine if $ \int_3^{\infty}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}\,dx $ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Determine whether the following integral is convergent or divergent without evaluating it.
￼￼￼(Whichever answer is correct, you must show why it is true.)
$$
\int_3^{\infty}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}\,dx
$$

I know that convergence depends on the existence of the limit. How do you find the limit of this equation? Is there a short cut (theorem, principle, memorizable equation) that simplifies this?

This is the first step...

$$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \int_3^t\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}$$

Comment: I am trying to better understand convergence.

Comment: I can include the progress I've made in the question, but I'm not sure if what I've done is correct.

Comment: I edited it with the work I've done so far

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation*}
\int_3^{\infty}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}\,dx \;>\;
\int_3^{\infty}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4}}\,dx  \;=\;
\int_3^{\infty}\frac{x+1}{x^2}\,dx \;>\;
\int_3^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^2}\,dx \;=\;
\int_3^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,dx
\end{equation*}
The last integral diverges.

Comment: Simpler to use $\sqrt{x^4}$ instead of $\sqrt{x^4+x^4}$. (And perhaps $2x$ instead of $x+1$.)

Comment: You're certainly right on the first one. I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me. But for the second one, doesn't that go the wrong way since $x+1 < 2x$?

Comment: Whoops! But then it's even simpler: use $x$ instead of $x+1$ :-)

Comment: I've edited my answer to include both of your excellent suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: From the ratio test you can obtain, that the interval behaves as integral of $(1/x)$, hence is divergent:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}}{\dfrac1x}=1.
$$

Comment: how is the ratio test performed when there are two "x" phrases on the bottom? How does this fit into the "L= lim(n->infinity) a(n+1)/a(n)"?

Comment: @Renée I hope that my extended hint is more clear now.

Comment: Yes definitely more clear, thank you! I have another question though... I was under the impression that if there was a definite limit, the series was automatically convergent. Here, even though the limit = 1, why is the series divergent?

Answer (score -1):

**HINT:**

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^{x}} < \frac{(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^4 - x}}$

Does $\displaystyle \int_{3}^{\infty} 2^{-x} dx$ converge?

Then find a function greater.